# After r.js build Backbone and Handlebars are undefined in App Loader

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

I have a problem with an [r.js build](https://github.com/s-a/boilerplate-r.js-jquery-backbone-handlebars/blob/master/_build/_page.sh#L2) in my app loader.

Unbuild mode is working perfect but after a build with r.js the variables in [app_loader.js#L7](https://github.com/s-a/boilerplate-r.js-jquery-backbone-handlebars/blob/master/www-root-dev/assets/js/app_loader.js#L7)  bb and hb are `undefined`. So far I work around by using global variables Handlebars und Backbone but what is wrong with this [shim](https://github.com/s-a/boilerplate-r.js-jquery-backbone-handlebars/blob/master/www-root-dev/assets/js/app_main.js#L5)?

Comment: I tried to run your r.js build but got this: `Tracing dependencies for: app_main Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/explunit/TESTPROJECT/www-root/assets/js/mvc/../../../mvc/demo.html'`

Comment: Also, I don't understand your use of the deprecated `order!` plugin. Can you explain?

Comment: I just cloned from scratch and executed /_build/_page.sh. It runs fine here. There is no special reason for `order!` usage. It is orientated on on existing code samples in the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed your global references and tested this locally. It works.

**build.js** - updated to use app_main as config file

```
({
    optimizeCss: "standard",
    removeCombined: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    appDir: "../www-root-dev",
    dir: "../www-root",
    keepBuildDir: false,
    optimize: "uglify2",
    mainConfigFile: "../www-root-dev/assets/js/app_main.js",
    modules: [{
        name: "app_main"
    }]
})
```

**app.js**

```
define(["app_loader"], function(loader){
    var $ = loader.$, Backbone = loader.Backbone;  
    ...
});
```

**app_loader.js**

```
define(["jquery","underscore","backbone","handlebars","app_routes"],
function($, _, Backbone, Handlebars, router){ 
    return {
        $: $.noConflict(),
        _: _,
        Backbone: Backbone,
        router: router,
        Handlebars: Handlebars
    };
});
```

**app_main.js** - updated to simplify paths

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './assets/js',
    paths: {
        mvc: '../../mvc'
    },
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_' //the exported symbol
        },
        backbone : {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone' 
        },
        handlebars: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function(App){  
    App.initialize(); 
});
```

**app_routes.js**

```
define(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "mvc/demo.view.js", "mvc/demo.model.js"], function($, _, Backbone, DemoView, DemoModel) { ... });
```

**demo.model.js**

```
define(["backbone"], function(Backbone) { ... });
```

**demo.view.js**

```
define(["jquery","backbone","text!mvc/demo.html"], function($, Backbone,demoTemplate) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because in your shim you have exported backbone and handlebar as Backbone and Handlebars respectively,

```
backbone : {
         deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
         exports: 'Backbone' 
       },
handlebars:{
         deps: ['jquery'],
         exports: 'Handlebars'
       },
```

and in your app_loader.js#L7 you are using it as bb and hb.

Either in shim export it as bb and hb:

```
backbone : {
             deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
             exports: 'bb' 
           },
handlebars:{
             deps: ['jquery'],
             exports: 'hb'
           },
```

or use Backbone and Handlebars in app_loader.js#L7 instead of bb and hb:

```
define("app_loader",[ 
  "jquery",
    "underscore",
  "backbone",
  "handlebars",
    "order!assets/js/app_routes.js"
], function(jQuery, underscore, Backbone, Handlebars, router){
```

I am also new to backbone and requirejs but it should help.

Comment: hb and bb variable names are a workaround. Your changes in shim cause that Backbone and Handlebars will not be exported even in unbuild mode.

Comment: Ya,that's true. Then go with the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

I have forked your github project and use grunt requirejs to run the optimization.

I manage to run the site and didn't notice any console errors in Chrome.

Comment: The project works after build because I worked around as described. I ve updated the sample project and added console.log messages. 

You will nitoce now 

Backbone undefined app_main.js:6  
Handlebars undefined app_main.js:6  

In Build Mode

While they are defined in unbuild mode.

Answer (score 0):

I took your project and noticed the errors in your build. I then made some changes to your app_main.js file as follows. Let me know if this solves your issues? Solved mine.

```
// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
// Their usage will become more apparent futher along in the tutorial.
require.config({

    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: '_' //the exported symbol
        },
        backbone : {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone' 
        },
        handlebars: {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        }

    },

    paths: {
        appLoader:  'app_loader',
        jquery:     'jquery',
        underscore: 'underscore',
        backbone :  'backbone' ,
        handlebars: 'handlebars'

    }
});

require([
'app'
], function(App){  
    App.initialize(); 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are refreshing, and your browser is not caching the previous build. Checked it a few times and it definitely solved the issue of Backbone not being defined when the application is built.

Comment: My Chrome Browser does not cache dev tools are loaded.

Comment: So what error are you getting? Backbone not being defined? What's your console throwing?